# Remove Column From mySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query of a gravity forms table in a database. I need to format the result for a cyfe dashboard. Which means I need to remove the uid column. Although I can't seem to get it worked out properly

```
SELECT entry_id as uid
,(SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=1.3 and entry_id = uid) as 'NAME'
,(SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=3 and entry_id = uid) as 'PHONE'
FROM wp_gf_entry_meta
GROUP BY uid ORDER BY uid
```

**Current Results (DUMMY DATA)**

[image]

**Needed Results (DUMMY DATA)**

[image]

Tried this:

```
SELECT *
,(SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=1.3 and entry_id = uid) as 'NAME'
,(SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=3 and entry_id = uid) as 'PHONE'
FROM wp_gf_entry_meta
GROUP BY uid ORDER BY uid
```

Error: Unknown column 'uid' in 'where clause'

I have also tried this:

```
SELECT *
,(SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=1.3) as 'NAME'
,(SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=3) as 'PHONE'
FROM wp_gf_entry_meta
```

Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Also Tried This:

```
SELECT
,(SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=1.3 and entry_id = uid) as 'NAME'
,(SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=3 and entry_id = uid) as 'PHONE'
FROM wp_gf_entry_meta
GROUP BY entry_id
```

Error: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '(SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=1.3 and entry_id = uid) ' at line 2

Comment: Please edit your question to include the query you try to run and add the error message you get when you try to run it.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand. I did include that at the top? As well as the results. There is no error.

Comment: It looks like the query at the top is the query which returns three columns. But what is your query you tried to get only two columns? And what is the error message you get when you try to run it?

Comment: I understand, I have tried a number of leads that I found on stackoverflow, but none of them got me close. I am not the strongest at SQL. So I am more stuck and not sure how to proceed to get the expected results.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the queries you tried and the results (or error messages) you get. It sounds like a simple task to remove the `entry_id as uid, ` part from that query but there might be error messages we currently don't see yet.

Comment: Just remove `entry_id as uid` from your `SELECT`. Then change `GROUP BY uid` as `GROUP BY entry_id`. Should be exactly what you want.

Comment: I gave that a try too. The error seems to be related to the subqueries returning multiple values.

Comment: @DarkSpartan47 Oh. That makes sense. The correlated subqueries here are relying on that field being named `uid` which is the alias of `entry_id` which of course doesn't exist anymore since it's missing in the SELECT.

Comment: Yes! exactly. That's where the trouble is. I need to use that field in the sub query to prevent the multiple values. But I don't necessarily want to show the column.

Comment: @DarkSpartan47 yea.. the confusion is definitely understandable because of the complexity that the correlated subqueries introduce. They make perfect sense here, but they present a pretty high hurdle for someone new to SQL. I have rewritten in my answer using some LEFT OUTER JOIN's which, I believe, makes the SQL more approachable. It should also give you the results you are after. Win-win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Correlated subqueries which are relying on aliases and dark magic, just switch this to a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT meta2.meta_value as 'NAME', meta3.meta_value as 'PHONE'
FROM wp_gf_entry_meta meta1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  wp_gf_entry_meta meta2
        ON meta1.entry_id = meta2.entry_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_gf_entry_meta meta3
        ON meta1.entry_id = meta3.entry_id
GROUP BY meta1.entry_id /*uid*/
```

Now it's clearer what's going on and dropping a single column doesn't also mean losing your alias that is required for those correlated subqueries to work.

IF you wanted to stick with the correlated subquery approach, you need to alias the table in the `FROM` clause for use in your subqueries (since we lost the nice alias for the `uid`):

```
SELECT
   (SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=1.3 and entry_id = meta_uid.entry_id) as 'NAME',
   (SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=3 and entry_id = meta_uid.entry_id) as 'PHONE'
FROM wp_gf_entry_meta AS meta_uid
GROUP BY entry_id
```

If this is still complaining about multiple results in the subquery(s) then switch over to the LEFT OUTER JOIN where multiple results are allowed through. Then you can see why it's multiplying and correct it in the SQL instead of working blindfolded through the correlated subqueries.

Comment: This is perfect. Is there a benefit to one solution over the other. Also for anyone else who looks at this the table names in the left outer join statement say wb instead of wp.

Comment: Fixed those `wb`. Whoops. I don't believe you are going to see any difference between the two queries here. The correlated subqueries here were acting, effectively, like a LEFT OUTER JOIN. The only difference is that a subquery in a SELECT can only return one result per row from the main table. The LEFT OUTER JOIN will gladly allow through many rows from the joined tables. That may not be what you want, but in one case you'll get a dark mysterious error (the one you are getting now) and in the other case you get more rows than expected and you can see what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to drop the first `SELECT entry_id as uid` and leverage WITH instead.

```
WITH entry_id as uid
    (SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=1.3 and entry_id = uid) as 'NAME'
    ,(SELECT meta_value from wp_gf_entry_meta where meta_key=3 and entry_id = uid) as 'PHONE'
    FROM wp_gf_entry_meta
    GROUP BY uid ORDER BY uid
```